# navbar fadeIn & fadeOut at scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

hi i was doing a search about how to make my navbar fadeIn while scrolling down and fadeOut while scrolling Up and found nice topic helped me alot 
[Fading bootstrap navbar on scrolldown, while changing text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976498/fading-bootstrap-navbar-on-scrolldown-while-changing-text-color)

also http://jsfiddle.net/f5UTL/

the problem is it's not fading in or out while scrolling its just appear and disappear no dynamic animation it's even moving my page while this process it is appreciated if some one told me where was my mistake at

```js
< script >
    $(function () {
        var header = $('.opaque');
        $(window).scroll(function () {

            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (scroll >= 300) {
                header.removeClass('opaque').addClass('navbar-fixed-top').fadeIn();
            } else {
                header.removeClass('navbar-fixed-top').fadeOut().addClass('opaque');
            }
        });
    });
< /script>
```

```css
.navbar-fixed-top {
    
    background-color: rgba(128,128,128,1);
    transition: background-color all 2s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color all 2s;
    -moz-transition: background-color all 2s;
    -o-transition: background-color all 2s;
  }
.navbar-fixed-top .opaque { 
    background-color: rgba(128,128,128,0);
    transition: background-color all 2s ;
    -webkit-transition: background-color all 2s ;
    -moz-transition: background-color all 2s ;
    -o-transition: background-color all 2s ;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the simplified version of what you want to achieve .

```
$(function() {
    //caches a jQuery object containing the header element
    var header = $('#nav');
    $(window).scroll(function() {
       var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
       if (scroll >= header.height()) {
         header.fadeOut();
       } else {
        header.fadeIn();
      }
    });
});
```

Hope it will help you to continue.

updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5UTL/168/).

Comment: Thanks but if you checked my javascript code you will find it the same already

Comment: Yes, but there are some differences, you are using static value to compare with scroll position, which is bad practice also I changed `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` functions places. Please check the code above, it is worked for me in your fiddle . Thanks .

Comment: i did try it but switched fadeOut with fadeIn because i need it to fadeIn on scrolling down not up but when page load the navbar appear and static even with scrolling down so i have to scroll up again to make it work with scrolling down and i need it to be transparent after page loading then appear on scrolling down dynamically

Comment: but at least now page is not moving when the navbar appear or disappear which is good step ^_^

Comment: i checked the updated fiddle this code made to make navbar fadeOut on scrolling down and disappear while i need to make it fadeIn on scrolling down and am still missing the animation on color transition idon't know why it's not doing it well